# Reference manual/tutorial for x86 SIMD intrinsics?

Tags: simd, sse, intrinsics, avx

I'm looking into using these to improve the performance of some code but good documentation seems hard to find for the functions defined in the `*mmintrin.h` headers, can anybody provide me with pointers to good info on these?

EDIT: particularly interested in a very basic tutorial on how to get started.

Comment: ?Closed?? Why??? isn'n this question relevant... isn't the answers (the 2 given) helpful....

Comment: There are now some links in the SSE tag wiki: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sse/info

Answer (score 17):

There's a handy online **Intel Intrinsics Guide** at https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html - it covers all Intel SIMD stuff from MMX through the various flavours of SSE up to AVX2 *et al*.

You can also get the following PDFs from [Intel](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/):

- Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual, Volume 2A: Instruction Set Reference, A-M (253666-021)
- Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual, Volume 2B: Instruction Set Reference, N-Z (253667-021)
- Intel® SSE4 Programming Reference (D91561-001)

Comment: Very useful, but took me a bit of time to figure out how to get the thing to run on Linux. First time I've ever seen a shell script that had spaces and parentheses in the file name.

Comment: The Intel Intrinsics Guide is cryptic and useless for beginners. Isn't there anything more pedagogical and beginner-friendly (probably with some hello world examples)?

Comment: The links to the intrinsics guide are no longer functional, and redirect to  https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/overview.html instead.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity: The previous link was to a thing you could install locally, for Mac/Linux/Windows.  If that's totally gone, the answer should just be simplified to just talk about the online guide where searching works via javascript.

Comment: I apologize, I honestly did not realize that the two links were originally pointing to two different things.  I thought instead that the previous edit has simply not changed the first when he changed the third.  Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 10):

This is the best introduction to MMX/SSE programming I ever found. (I've programmed SSE2 for 5 years and I still find this tutorial to be the most conceptually clear.)

http://www.tommesani.com/Docs.html

This is not a complete list of instructions; so once you're ready to learn more, do start reading the Intel intrinsics guide as @PaulR suggests.

One important thing to keep in mind is that MMX/SSE tend to be severely limiting in terms of movements of data (shuffle or arbitrary permutation, or change of single element). This is a limitation of CPU silicon design. Scatter-gather instructions were only added a few years ago, and might not even be available on your customer's computers.

There is a large repertoire of vectorization tricks for MMX/SSE similar to the way http://www.hackersdelight.org/ prescribes tricks for exploiting bit-parallel operations.